# ROUND a big number at Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

In Amazon Athena, I want to round a big number to output me as decimal precision 2.
For example, I have `1.4309491454947177E11` which is equivalent to `143094914549.47177`, so I expect result to be `143094914549.47`

I am doing

```sql
SELECT ROUND(1.4309491454947177E11, 2)
```

But it is giving me wrong output `1.43`.
Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Yes, updated statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is correct it is converting it to 2 decimals and you can use it in any downstream. It is just displayed as exponential. Similar to the way you see in excel and when you click on excel cell it displays actual value.

If you want to see data in 2 digit format.Cast will work make sure no of digits in cast is more than actual value

```
    select cast(Round(1.4309491454947177E11 ,2) as decimal(20,2))
```

Comment: I believe Round is not working for such a big number but yes if we cast to decimal using statement it works.

select CAST(1.4309491454947177E11 as decimal(30,2))